# One-to-many relations from table to itself in WebSQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, web-sql

I am trying to make an application in Phonegap and using WebSQL to create local db. I have a table called stars ...there are many actors/stars ... on selecting the details of one star, I want to show suggestions for other related stars like their relatives.. I can do it as Self Join. But this will be a  one to one relationship only. Here are my tables...

```
var sql =
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stars ( "+
    "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    "firstName VARCHAR(50), " +
    "middleName VARCHAR(50), " +
    "lastName VARCHAR(50), " +
    "title VARCHAR(50), " +
    "picture VARCHAR(200))";
tx.executeSql(sql);

sql =
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS star_details ( "+
    "id INTEGER, " +
    "biography VARCHAR(1000), " +
    "trivia VARCHAR(1000), " +
    "birthday VARCHAR(50), " +
    "website VARCHAR(50), FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES stars(id))";
tx.executeSql(sql);

sql =
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recent_movies ( "+
    "id INTEGER, " +
    "recent_movie1 VARCHAR(1000), " +
    "recent_movie2 VARCHAR(1000), " +
    "recent_movie3 VARCHAR(50), FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES stars(id))";
tx.executeSql(sql);
```

Now I am trying ways to create another table star_relations ...but confused on how to do that?

One star may be associated with 3 stars - one brother and his 2 son
Similarly on selecting the star(son) - relations will be father, 1 brother and an uncle....

So confused on how to achieve this .

Answer (score 0):

This is hierarchy is a bit problematic because you can have holes in it, so for it to work well you have to insert a record for each relation. i.e.

Star A can have a brother and an uncle in stars, but not have the father.

So you can create a reference table "relations" where you insert the type of relations and then have a different table where you cross reference two stars and relations:

relations:
id INTEGER
description VARCHAR(100)

stars_relations
id integer
star1_id INTEGER
relation_id INTEGER
star2_id INTEGER

This might give you a little work to fill in the relations, but i think it can work.